South Korea transit visa waiver program
I am a Chinese passport holder with permanent residency in the UK. I would like to travel to South Korea and then Australia (UK -> South Korea -> Australia -> UK), and will apply online for the Australian visitor visa (subclass 600). Based on this plan I am wondering whether I would satisfy the criteria for the 30-day transit visa exemption scheme for South Korea?
Thank you!
